だから as its own phrase after a clause
The song Call You... Kimi to Boku no Mirai has two verses with a single verb/conjunction though they could be a part of the main associated lyric.

この星を守る  何が起っても
僕も君も生きている  証！だから！

No matter what happens, I will protect this planet
It is proof that me and you (we) are alive! That's why!



今  僕は誓う  取り戻せ  未来
明日へ向かう  真実の  扉！開けろ！

I now swear to take back the future?
The gateway of truth leading to tomorrow! Open it!/Open the gateway of truth leading to tomorrow!


The whole song's overall structure is confusing with its many inverted/relative clauses, but だから confuses me the most. It is its own phrase and comes after its corresponding phrase. I've usually seen it come first in a sentence or in the middle as a conjunction connecting two clauses. だから seems to explain the preceding sentence, but it seems to explain itself just fine.


A。だから、B。
A. Therefore, B.
B。Aだから。
B. It's because A.

As you seem to understand, both are possible ways of using だから, so you need to understand the entire flow of the lyrics to see which is working as the reason for which.
After hearing the song, The part after だから doesn't seem to be working as the reason for something. So I think this is what the lyrics are saying:

何が起ってもこの星を守る。(この星は)僕も君も生きている証だから。
= (この星は)僕も君も生きている証だから、何が起ってもこの星を守る。

だから is emphasized, but it's still part of the previous "sentence". So the English translation in the linked page appears to be correct.

So, can it be combined into a singular phrase instead of being kept separate? Can it also apply to the other verse?
